# Quotes in VBA formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong i'm trying to add quotation marks to "engine oils" below. but it keeps giving me an error.

can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

```
Sheets("PDF Copy").Cells(t, 6).Formula = "=IF(Daily!I8" & i & "=""ENGINE OILS"" ,DAILY!I" & i & ",Daily!K" & i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket.

```
'=IF(Daily!I810="ENGINE OILS",Daily!I10,Daily!K10)
Sheets("PDF Copy").Cells(2, 6).Formula = _
    "'=IF(Daily!I8" & i & "=""ENGINE OILS"" ,DAILY!I" & i & ",Daily!K" & i & ")"
```